# Z3: Translate a BoolRef into a BitVecVal

Tags: z3, z3py

I am trying to simulate the `x86` assembly code using `z3` formulas. Currently, I am trapped in simulating the semantics of `setnz` opcode.

the semantics of `setnz` is defined as

```
checking the value of CPU flag `ZF`, and if it is equal to 1, then set a register byte as 1, otherwise set it as 0.
```

For example, the above procedure can be simulated in this way:

```
python
>>> from z3 import *
>>> a = BitVecVal(1, 1)
>>> c = (a == 1)
>>> set_register("al", c)
```

However, **note that the type of `c` is a `BoolRef`, and I would like to set the value of `al` as a 8-bit long `BitVecVal`.**

So here is my question:

1. I am following the best practice to simulate such `set` opcodes?
2. If so, how can I translate a `BoolRef` into a 8-bit long `BitVecVal` in order to set the register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use If:

```
If(c, BitVecVal(1,1), BitVecVal(0,1))
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much for the answer!